# Run a program in pycharm under anaconda enviroment

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, python-3.5

l have a program that l run using anacoda environment. l have anaconda3, python3.5
to run l do the following steps.

```
source activate my_env
python3.5 demo.py
```

However when l'm pycharm editor, while l run `demo.py` l got the following :

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/ahmed/Downloads/crnn.pytorch-master/demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/Downloads/crnn.pytorch-master/demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named 'torch'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

because the code exported and the packages are installed (requires) with conda environment. 
My question is how to activate conda enviroment in pycharm so that to be able to run the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help you.

http://blog.cyberpunk.bike/blog/how-to-make-conda-work-with-pycharm

Also conda pycharm package

https://anaconda.org/chen/pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
source activate my_env
conda info
```

to find out where the environment is on your machine. Then go to your project settings, and change the interpreter for that project to be your conda environment,